# Changing values on graph axis generated by mathplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph

I'm having real problems with putting names instead of numerical values on the graph.
I'm reading data from excel file, and want to draw a bar and circle graph out of it.

Is there any easy way to do that?

[I want to have specific names instead of 0,1,2 (..) on x axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiTJY.png)

[The data in excel:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdaHd.png)

The code I have

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def DrawGraphDamagePerSecond(data): 
    damageDone.plot(kind='bar')
    plt.xlabel('Name')
    plt.ylabel('DPS')
    plt.title('Damage Per Second')
    plt.show()


 
excel = pd.ExcelFile('path to my excel')
damageDone = pd.read_excel(excel, 'Damage Done',decimal=',')
healingDone = pd.read_excel(excel, 'Healing Done', decimal=',')


DrawGraphDamagePerSecond(damageDone)
```

Comment: Your dataframe's index is used for the x tick labels.  So, `damageDone.set_index('Name').plot(kind='bar')` might work for you.

Comment: You should not [post code or data as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors), but paste your *actual* code or image into your question. This way, you enable users to troubleshoot your problem in their local environments.